# Moving from Activities to Fragments: how to display the menu just for 1 Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I am an Android programming newbie trying to move from Activities to Fragments.

I have a simple Bluetooth app with 3 Activities:

1. MainActivity (with "Settings" in menu)
2. SettingsActivity with few checkboxes and seekbars
3. ScanningActivity showing Bluetooth devices in a list

This is a screenshot of the MainActivity, with an ellipsis menu in top-right corner:

[image: main]

I am trying to change my app to have a single MainActivity, which displays one of 3 Fragments (MainFragment, SettingsFragment or ScanningFragment):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
                        MainListener, /* my 3 custom interfaces */
                        SettingsListener, 
                        ScanningListener, 
                        BleWrapperUiCallbacks {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // empty FrameLayout

    Fragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.root, fragment, "main")
        .commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Fragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .replace(R.id.root, fragment, "settings")
                .commit();
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**My problem** is that currently the "Settings" menu is always displayed - while I only need to display it when the MainFragment is shown (but not when SettingsFragment or ScanningFragment are shown).

How to solve this best?

And do I have to introduce an enum variable, which I can query to find which of the 3 Fragments is currently displayed or is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in the fragment you wish to show the menu, not in your activity. In the others fragments you don't want to display the menu, use `setHasOptionMenu(false)`.

To get your current fragment, use the `findFragmentByTag()` from your `FragmentManager`

Comment: Thanks, but where to call `setHasOptionMenu(false)`, should I call it in Fragment's `onCreateView()`? And how to use `findFragmentByTag()` for finding currently displayed Fragment - wouldn't it for example return not-null if MainFragment is in back stack and SettingsFragment is shown?

Comment: Yes, you may use it in `onCreateView()`. You could set your fragment's tag to `null` in `onDettach()` or in `onDestroyView` since you're using `replace()`

Answer (score 1):

You can Override onCreateOptions menu in the fragment that should have the menu and only inflate it there.

In the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_fragment_menu);
}
```